# chrome extensions парсить контент расширением

Tags: javascript, парсер, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь парсить контент страницы расширением.
Не могу найти инфу как попасть на контент страницы, и парсить не расширение, а страницу.
Итоговая задача, спарсить на странице то что внутри класа, и сложить в textarea.
Прошу помощи сообщества.

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 

        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        q = jQuery('.class1').html();
        console.log(q);

    });
    }, false);
}, false);
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>parser</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Check:</h1>
        <button id="checkPage">Check</button>
        <textarea id="num123"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "OLX parser",
"description": "This extension will parse OLX",
"version": "1.0.5",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
],
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}]

}
```

Comment: Парсер в content_script должен быть, очевидно же

Comment: https://github.com/aka-darth/myscore_parser_chrome_extension вот можете поизучать мой парсер, он правда длинноват, но там вы сможете почерпнуть пару идей, как вообще всё организовать

Comment: "content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "jquery.min.js","parser.js" ],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }]
это позволило парсить q = jQuery('.class1').html();
Но я не нашел в вашем скрипте как вы сохраняете это в хранилище. Как получить доступ с расширения к к скрипту контента, либо наоборот - как передать данные в расширение?Я бы не спрашивал, но я не нахожу таких примеров просто, либо описания.

Comment: Получить доступ к скрипту контента - https://github.com/aka-darth/myscore_parser_chrome_extension/blob/master/open_detail_statistics.js#L24 вот тут есть с помощью тега script

Comment: В расширении есть три части - бэкграунд, попап и контент скрипты. Общение между ними происходит с помощью chrome.runtime.onMessage / sendMessage

Comment: вы же под скриптами контента подразумеваете скрипты страницы, в которую вы вставляете еще и content_script расширения?

Comment: chrome.runtime.sendMessage посылает сообщения сразу всем частям расширения

Comment: там у меня в конце каждого скрипта обработчики повешены, которые слушают эти сообщения, которые приходят от других частей. Мой парсер собирает данные в background скрипте (единственное надежное место)

Comment: вот тут парсер отсылает в бэкграунд скрипт собранные данные https://github.com/aka-darth/myscore_parser_chrome_extension/blob/master/parser.js#L60

Comment: вот тут бэкграунд скрипт их ловит https://github.com/aka-darth/myscore_parser_chrome_extension/blob/master/background.js#L441

Comment: Спасибо большое, по вашему примеру получилось "разговорить" этих троих.