# Расширение для хрома ругается. Не работают скрипты

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Только начал делать расширения для Хрома.
Цель- сделать парсер на javascript.
Я хочу сделать фрейм, в который буду грузить страницу для парсинга и нужно получить доступ к её элементам из главного окна.
Так как просто так не достучишься к фрейму из другого домена из за политики безопасности- решил сделать расширение.
Вот только как там с политиками безопасности быть? В консоли куча эроров- скрипты не работают- вообщем что-то не то.
Вот код манифеста

```
{ 
  "name": "myParser", 
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "2.0", 
  "description": "Parser", 
  "permissions": [
     "<all_urls>",
     "unlimitedStorage"
   ], 
  "app": {
      "launch": {
         "local_path": "main.html"
      }
   },
   "icons": { 
    "16": "css/images/Spider-16.png" 
   }
}
```

Main.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my.js"></script>

<frameset  cols="250,*">
  <frame src="page1.html" name="topFrame"  >
  <frame src="ЗДЕСЬ УРЛ САЙТА,КОТОРЫЙ ПАРСИМ" name="topFrame" scrolling="no"  id="Parseframe">
</frameset>
```

В my.js кидаю обычный алерт и он не работает,
кроме этого ещё пишет мне разную гадость, типа
**Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'ha256-AJl абракадабра'.**

**Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-AJl абракадабра'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.**

Что нужно прописать, что б хоть базовый функционал работал?
Спасибо

Comment: Таким путем боюсь ничего не выйдет. Надо писать content script, который браузер будет загружать на все разрешенные страницы. all_urls - там видимо `*` должна быть. Если надо пребирать пачку url, то может понадобится еще background скрипт, который имеет возможность управлять табами в браузере, т.е. например сказать табу загрузить в себя такую то страницу. Это надо потому, что content скрипт не заработает пока страница не прогрузится и завершиться как только браузер начнет грузить другую страницу. И никаких .html своих точно не понадобится, только js

Comment: Т.е. начинать надо с этого https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts  А потом для расширения функционала возможно понадобятся backgroup и другие виды скриптов

Comment: А Вы можете подсказать ссылку, где подобное делается? Как мне полностью все ограничения убрать, что б у расширения были супер права на всё?

Comment: Вам просто фреймы вообще не нужны. Загружаете требуемую страницу в браузере, если расширение с контент скриптом для которого разрешена работа на этом сайте (а вы можете и `*` т.е. все сайты разрешить) есть, то браузер запустит ваш скрипт и ему будет доступен document данной страницы, т.е. все ее содержимое

Comment: @RakzinRoman вот недавно было: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483176/chrome-extensions-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC  и конкретно комментарии с ссылками: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483176/chrome-extensions-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC#comment558562_483176

Comment: @RakzinRoman http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483176/chrome-extensions-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC#comment558796_483176   и так далее

Comment: Хах))вчера...-не видел. спасибо

Comment: @RakzinRoman А вы уверены что вам нужен парсер в виде расширения? Это вообще не лучший вариант вплане производительности и скорости работы, т.к. браузером производится много лишних телодвижений (отрисовка страницы и тд)

Comment: На nodejs вы можете просто грузить страницы как текст, при этом у вас не будет проблем с политикой безопастности (надо будет только аккуратно подделать заголовки, и всё - можно парсить).

Comment: Я в node не очень разбираюсь, хотя на Javascript пишу. Мне не важно на каком языке или расширении(я работаю на Javascript/php/Golang -в чём-то из этого) Производительность я перетерплю и могу подождать....главное, что б что-то было

Comment: + есть [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), которая делает парсинг html удобным почти как в браузере

Comment: [Пример](http://pastebin.com/spdV2GZD) парсера на nodejs

Comment: @RakzinRoman попробуйте на node, вам понравится)

Comment: )))) Ок.  Спасибо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если вы считаете, что вопрос - дубликат, отметьте это тревогой или голосом за закрытие, а не просто комментарием.